# Runge-Kutta to solve 6DOF equations of motion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, simulation, runge-kutta-methods

## Aim:

I want to solve the 6DOF equations to model the flight dynamics of an aircraft (for a flight simulator) In order to do this, I need to solve multiple differential equations using the Runge-Kutta 4 algorithm.

After a bit of research, I can use the RK4 algorithm to solve simple 2 variable ODE's, but I have no idea how to apply it to multi-variable ODE's.

I only have an engineering background so I apologize if I have made a meal out of the terminology.

The equations are a bit hefty so I will only type one of them out...
See pg 10/32 for the full set of equations [Link to full set of equations](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/pdf/88596main_H-2276.pdf).

## Equations of Flight

*Time Derivative of Angle of Attack*
$$
\dot\alpha = \frac{\bar q S}{mV}C_Ncos(\alpha) + q-\tan(\beta)(p \cos(\alpha)+r \sin(\alpha) + \frac{g}{V}(\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta)\cos(\alpha)+\sin(\theta)\sin(\alpha))
$$

In these equations most of the variables are functions of time (like $
\dot \alpha, \bar q, V, p,q,r)
$

As a result, I am not sure how to proceed. I would be very grateful if someone could offer some help. Alternatively, if anyone has any experience of flight sims I would be delighted to learn how the number-crunching works.

Regards,

*Henry*

Comment: So I can just extend the RK method and solve each derivative one at a time?

Comment: No, all equations of the system are numerically solved simultaneously. For instance, with [RK1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) (= Euler method),
$$
{\boldsymbol y}_{n+1} = {\boldsymbol y}_{n} + (t_{n+1}-t_n)\, {\boldsymbol f}(t_{n},{\boldsymbol y}_{n}) \, ,
$$
whatever the dimension of $\boldsymbol y$.

Comment: I think that works, thank you.